# Whichis the correct way to display items from a list using keys in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is to create a product list and continuously display it when a product enters. For this I'm using keys (to distinguish between the products). From the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component) we know that:

> A "key" is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

I have a table where I display the products, each product have an ID, a description, a price and a quantity (quantity of that kind of products on the list). Every time a new product is added to the list it must display it after the last one displayed, but, if the product is already on the list, it must change the object data to show the new values. Example:

```
------------------------------------
| Description |  Price  | Quantity |
------------------------------------
|  Milk       |   $2.49 |     1    |
------------------------------------
```

So, when, for example, coffee is added it should appear like this:

```
------------------------------------
| Description |  Price  | Quantity |
------------------------------------
|  Milk       |   $2.49 |     1    |
------------------------------------
|  Coffee     |   $1.25 |     1    |
------------------------------------
```

But, when another milk is added, the values should be:

```
------------------------------------
| Description |  Price  | Quantity |
------------------------------------
|  Milk       |   $4.98 |     2    |
------------------------------------
|  Coffee     |   $1.25 |     1    |
------------------------------------
```

By now, using ES5 I have my Table class like this (**this is only the render function**):

```
return (
            <div className="data">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <table id="table" className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {<Product key={key} description={description} price={price} quantity={quantity} />}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 col-centered">
                    <div className="row"><Total key={total} total={total} /></div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <button href="#" className="btn btn-default btn-lg">Pagar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

Total, for this, is not relevant, that is working and it doesn't make any change to the table. To render a Product, here is the class:

```
var Product = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        quantity: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        description: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        producttotal: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        return{
            quantity: this.props.quantity,
            description: this.props.description,
            producttotal: this.props.producttotal
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.quantity}</td>
                <td>{this.props.description}</td>
                <td>{this.props.producttotal}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
});
```

Right now what React does is overwriting each item when it enters the list. As you can see is `Product` gets a key (that is the product ID), but the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) says:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

This happens when I use `props`, but for example if I change the state of `description`, `price` and `quantity` on `Product` with `this.setState`, then I get this warning:

> Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

So, which is the correct way to display items from a list using keys in ReactJS? I couldn't find much help in React documentation and forums. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I've written this in ES6, but hopefully this will help. I did not know what the Total component should look like, but calculated the meaningful `total` prop and displayed it so it should be simple to substitute.

As for your question, the "key" prop should always be a consistent identifier for the objects that will persist; Think of it as a hash value for cache-ing rendering. So for example, I used the price and name since those should be consistent in the app.

Typically, lists are mapped out. If you have a really long list, it might be a good idea to calculate those in componentWillReceiveProps to speed things up, but to be honest you should be using something like FLUX properly eventually where data stores end up taking care of that.

In any case, this is a pretty crude and incomplete example, but a table mapping out the products when given a list of items as a list of description strings working with the example you provided is here :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Product from './Product'

// basic mock data to work with
var items = ['Milk', 'Coffee', 'Milk', 'Coffee', 'Rice-cakes', 'Coffee'];

const Products =
[
    { description : 'Milk',       price : 2.49 },
    { description : 'Coffee',     price : 1.25 },
    { description : 'Rice-cakes', price : 1.49 }
];

class Table extends Component
{
    render ()
    {
        let productList = Products.map((product)=>
        {
            let quantity = items.filter((item)=>(item == product.description)).length,
                listItem =
                {
                    key         : (product.description + product.price), //any consistent hash will do here
                    description : product.description,
                    quantity,
                    price : (product.price * quantity)
                };

            return listItem;
        });

        let total = productList.map((p)=>p.price).reduce((a, b)=>(a+b),0);

        return (
            <div className="data">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <table id="table" className="table">
                        <thead>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {productList.map((p)=>(<Product {...p} />))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6 col-centered">
                    <div className="row">{total}</div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <button href="#" className="btn btn-default btn-lg">Pagar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my question explaining that the Total element is not relevant in here. By the way, your snippet shows an error: `{
  "message": "SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 8
}`

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that. I didn't mean for it to be executable. Not really familiar with StackExchange yet. I'll figure out how to take that out.

Comment: (should run just fine with a compiler that supports ES6 such as Babel though, or in Google Chrome)